# Maximum Ordered Ratio [Divide and Conquer Algorithms]

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Problem: "Suppose you are given as input a sequence of numbers [a1, a2, . . . , an] with n ≥ 2. Your goal is to find the largest ratio between two of these numbers where the numerator occurs after the denominator in the sequence."

Obviously, one can just sort the list and find the largest ratio, but given the problem constraint about the numerator and denominator that option is out. What can we do? So since the indexing is important sorting the array is pretty much out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to sort the array of elements. You can check it from end of the array to start of the array. See the algorithm below:

```
n = size of array  A // array are 0 indexed

numerator = A[n-1]
denominator = A[n-2]

max_numerator = max(A[n-1], A[n-2])

for i = n-3 to 0 {
    // assume A[i] as denominator
    if (numerator/denominator) < (max_numerator/A[i]) {
        numerator = max_numerator
        denominator = A[i]
    }
    max_numerator = max(max_numerator, A[i])
}
```